# How to add accessor method to element via plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a plugin that transforms the selected values from a dropdown menu into a concatenated string for use inside a text field.

The plugin is called like this:

```
info = $('select');
info.my_plugin({ /* plugin options */ });
```

What I would like to do is to add an accessor method on that element (preferably the jQuery collection), such that at a later time, I could call (after the code above):

```
info.get_values();
```

Which would call a private method (defined in the plugin) to return the currently set value for the jQuery element.

How do I modify my plugin to do this? My plugin is currently setup using this pattern:

```
$.fn.my_plugin = function(options) {};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using jQuery's `.data`. Like

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function (options) {

    var handler = {};

    this.data('myPlugin', handler);

    handler.options = options;

    handler.getValues = function () {
        // return some values
    };

    return this;

};
```

This way, the API your plugin exposes stays isolated and clean.

Then your users could do

```
$('select').myPlugin();

// later somewhere else
$('select').data('myPlugin').getValues();
```

*Note: I took this idea long ago from jQuery tools. Don't know if they are still doing this.*

Answer (score 0):

You would have to extend the $.fn object with another function, like this:

```
$.fn.my_plugin = function(options) {

    // ...your plugin code, setting the var "concatenatedDropDownString"

    $.fn.get_values = function(){
        return concatenatedDropDownString;
    };

    return concatenatedDropDownString;
};
```

Comment: This will only work if the plugin is used on a single element, since it will reassign `$.fn.get_values` on each call.

Comment: Yes it has to be modified for multiple elements. See the accepted answer above